# how change "live" to "on" in this script on jquery for the same functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert jQuery code from `live()` function to `on()` function with the same functionality.

If I click to a paragraph is create another one, when I click to span "Delete" the paragraph is removed.

If I change `live()` to `on()` the paragraph is created if I click to the first paragraph not each paragraph she was created before.

The demo code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ny38cLba/6/

HTML code

```
<body>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

</body>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 2;
    $("p").live("click", function() {
        $("<p>Paragraph " + i++ +" <span> Delete</span></p>").insertAfter(this);
    });
    $("span").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

If I want to hide a paragraph smoothly I use the following code :

```
$(this).on("click", "span",  function(){
$(this).parent().hide("slow",function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
})
```

but after the paragraph is deleted appears instead of a new paragraph.

See in this code: http://jsfiddle.net/a8e9v2m5/2/

Comment: Just change it to on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'on' instead of 'live' but not in the exactly same way when using dynamically generated DOM elements. You will have to bind the selector as well -

See, if this works -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colori = ["AntiqueWhite", "Aquamarine", "BurlyWood", "Chartreuse", "Coral", "DarkSalmon", "DodgerBlue", "GreenYellow", "LightBlue"];
    var i = 2;
    $(this).on("click", "p", function () {
        $("<p>Paragraph " + i++ + " <span> Sterge</span></p>").insertAfter(this);

        $(this).next().css("background-color", colori[i])

    });
    $(this).on("click", "span", function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in doc: http://api.jquery.com/live/

> $( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+

so,

```
$(document).on("click", "p", function() {
    $("<p>Paragraph " + i+++" <span> Delete</span></p>").insertAfter(this);
});
$(document).on("click", "span", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Also depends where you click, if you click on "Paragraph" it's a p so it'll add a new <p>, if you click on "Delete", it's a span so it'll remove parent.

Answer (score 1):

`.on()` uses a slightly different syntax. Instead of selecting the element you want to watch, select a parent, with a filter selector.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
var i=2;
$(document).on("click", "p", function(){
    $("<p>Paragraph "+ i++ +" <span> Delete</span></p>").insertAfter(this);

})
$(document).on("click", "span", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
})
```

See the [documentation for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in order to signal to others that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific to the `span` that is directly under the `p` tag

```
$(document).on("click", 'p', function(){
    $("<p>Paragraph "+ i++ +" <span> Delete</span></p>").insertAfter(this);

});
$(document).on("click", 'p span', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```